# .htaccess deny access to folder

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, directory

I'm new to apache... so be gentle with me guys :-)

I have used the following for denying access to a web folder with .htaccess:

```
order deny,allow
deny from all
```

I'm getting the "forbidden" page which is ok because I don't want web users, spiders or scrapers to access this folder.

But I am no longer able to access web folder though php script that I have written.  I thought that the applications where an exception to this.

Any help would be greatly appreciated by this newbie...

Thx...

Answer (score 1):

I might be wrong , go to check your ip address with myipaddress.com or whatever. Then you can `deny from all` and `allow from <YOUR IP>`

Comment: I will give this a try and get back to you wizztjh. Thx.

Comment: Hi again wizztjh. 

Yes it will work when I put my IP address as you specified.

But unfortunately the php script that is making the call to the restricted folder can be by anyone and not just me. So this approach will not work for me on this situation.

Comment: bt it work for this guy , try http://www.htpasswdgenerator.com/apache/htaccess.html . Btw , try do some google search ...

Comment: I will have a look through that site and also do some more google searching.  Hopefully I will be able to find a solution. Thanks for the help wizztjh :-)

Answer (score 1):

You might try using HTTP basic authentication to protect your files, but allow exceptions by providing a username and password in your PHP applications call. It's very simple, here is example for file_get_contents function: http://www.electrictoolbox.com/php-file-get-contents-sending-username-password/.

You should add something like this to your .htaccess and remove other restrictions:

```
AuthType Basic
AuthName "Restricted Files"
AuthUserFile /usr/local/apache/passwd/passwords
Require user wizztjh
```

Here is more info on this from apache docs: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/howto/auth.html